# How to add an IF to a FILTER command in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am filtering results from a table in google sheets, but I need to change the way I am creating my new filtered table because I need to separate the items with blueprint from the others that doesn't use recipes.

My filtered table is something like:

```
ITEMNAME BP MAT1 MAT2 MAT3
```

The data contains soma data similar to:

```
ITEMTYPE    PHOTO   ITEMNAME    SELLABLE    VENDORPRICE PRICE   DATE    STATS   LVL  "blueprint: ITEMNAME (BP_COUNT),  MATERIAL1 (MAT1_COUNT),  MATERIAL2 (MAT2_COUNT), MATERIAL3 (MAT3_COUNT)"
```

I can get the data from the columns, then split each material in different columns, but I don't know how to add an IF to the formula to make BP column in the filtered table empty when the items doesn't have blueprint. And the blueprint column in the dataset is a text one.

=FILTER(INDICE(SPLIT(Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000;",");0;1); Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(tienda)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(drop)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(quest)")

This give me results like:

```
BLUEPRINT                         MAT1            MAT2         MAT3
Copper Bar (5)      
Magic Recipe: Bone Blade (1)      Steel Bar (5)   Bone (20)
```

And I want this result:

```
BLUEPRINT                         MAT1            MAT2         MAT3
                                  Copper Bar (5)        
Magic Recipe: Bone Blade (1)      Steel Bar (5)   Bone (20)
```

I reached the point I cannot advance, because using a pattern like "=IFERROR(IF(FIND(string,range);value_iftrue);value_iffalse)" doesnt give me good results.

Any advice?

(for the sake: the formulas have ";" as separator because in Spanish version, formulas use that separator, you can ignore that)

Edit1: reallistic data example, with the expected result I need:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_FRyrmWsseZZVxMd2te37kbi-iaokuFDoCSHl1bh5M/edit#gid=892825449

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Something like this could help?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_FRyrmWsseZZVxMd2te37kbi-iaokuFDoCSHl1bh5M/edit#gid=892825449

Comment: I must tell myseslf that I  guess I found a way to make the IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(string,rage))) option to work properly...

=FILTER(SI.ERROR(SI(HALLAR("blueprint";INDICE(SPLIT(Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000;",");0;1));INDICE(SPLIT(Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000;",");0;1));""); Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(tienda)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(drop)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(quest)")

Comment: Well if its solved leave the working formula as answer below. If you still need help , need some understanding of the sample sheet since i am not sure what part is *blue print* here in the *weapons* tab?!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

=FILTER(SI.ERROR(SI(HALLAR("blueprint";INDICE(SPLIT(Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000;",");0;1));INDICE(SPLIT(Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000;",");0;1));""); Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(tienda)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(drop)"; Weapons!$J$2:$J$1000<>"(quest)")